How to install a certificate on XRDP installed on Ubuntu 22.04
I am setting up RDP connection in Ubuntu and trying to access it from another machine Windows,via Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection. The setup is fine and works properly with username and password.
However, we want to make it secure by ensuring that RDP is allowed only if a certificate is specified (much like public-private key pair used in SSH) along with password input.
I ran the following command in my Ubuntu machine (used no passphrase):
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out public.cert -days 365

It generated a cert file and a key file which I am trying to use in the ini file for XRDP (/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini) along with some other changes in settings:
enter image description here
After this I restart the service:
sudo systemctl restart xrdp

But even after this, I am able to connect to the machine via RDP from Windows 10 and it does not ask for any certificate and shows that it is secured. I also don't know how to provide one if it asks, since the Remote Desktop Connection.
Please help me in this issue how to install the certificate on xrdp to make it secure.

It seems like you've generated a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL, but XRDP is not configured to use this certificate for authentication. To make XRDP use your generated certificate for secure RDP connections, you need to update its configuration to point to the generated key and certificate files.
Here's what you need to do:

Update XRDP Configuration: Edit the XRDP configuration file /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini and specify the paths to your generated key and certificate files.Open the file in a text editor, and find the [ssl] section. Update the key_file and cert_file parameters to point to the locations of your private.key and public.cert files respectively.

[ssl]
...
key_file=/path/to/private.key
cert_file=/path/to/public.cert

Restart XRDP Service: After saving the changes to xrdp.ini, restart the XRDP service to apply the new configuration:

sudo systemctl restart xrdp

Connect with Remote Desktop Connection: Now, when you attempt to connect to the Ubuntu machine from Windows using Remote Desktop Connection, it should prompt you to select a certificate. You'll need to import the public certificate (public.cert) into the Windows certificate store beforehand.After importing the certificate, when you connect using Remote Desktop Connection, it should present the certificate for authentication.

Certificate Validation: To ensure that only connections with valid certificates are allowed, you might also need to configure XRDP to require client certificates. This can be done by setting require_client_cert=yes in the [ssl] section of xrdp.ini.


[ssl]
...
require_client_cert=yes
With this configuration, XRDP will only allow connections from clients that present a valid certificate.
PS: If you're exploring alternatives for RDP servers on Linux, you might want to consider ThinLinc. ThinLinc offers a robust remote desktop solution with features tailored for secure and efficient remote access.

I have configured it, but the connection is still not secure.
